# IEnumerable MVC Controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, web, ienumerable

I am trying to pass a var from a controller and access the information inside a view.

Inside the controller i have the following LINQ statement that totals up a sum of some columns that i need. I have in the past just passed the var to a list and then passed the list across.

The problem is that i am unsure as to how i pass this var across.

The following is the Controller code

```
    var GoodProduct =
new
{
    CastGoodSum =
        (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
         where item.ProductionHour >= StartShift && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate
         select item).Sum(x => x.CastGood),

    CastScrap =
        (from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
         where item.ProductionHour >= StartShift && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate
         select item).Sum(x => x.Scrap),

    MachinedSum = 
    (
    from item in db.tbl_dppITHr
    where item.ProductionHour >= StartShift && item.ProductionHour <= EndDate
    select item).Sum(x => x.Machined),
};

        return View(GoodProduct);
```

The view i am using is strongly typed i with the following IEnmerable

```
@model IEnumerable<int?>
```

I have also tried

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.tbl_dppITHr>
```

This worked fine when i was passing a single value type but since i am doing a sum i get the following error.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType2`3[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]'.
```

Anyone know how to pass this var across?

Comment: I suppose GoodProduct is not an array, but a single object. Can you precise his type ?

Comment: GoodProduct appears to be an anonymous object, containing 3 nullable integers. If GoodProduct was instead an instance of a strongly-typed class, then this class could be used as your view's model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have it now, you would need to use:

```
@model dynamic
```

as you are creating a dynamic object which you then pass to the view.

However, I prefer to create a strongly typed view model and pass that to the view.
i.e.

```
public class GoodProductViewModel {
    public int CastGoodSum {get;set;}
    public int CastScrap {get;set;}
    public int MachinedSum {get;set;}
}
```

Then populate that in your controller...

```
var GoodProduct = new GoodProductViewModel
{
    CastGoodSum = ....,
    CastScrap = ...,
    MachinedSum = ...
};

return View(GoodProductViewModel);
```

And use `@model GoodProductViewModel` in your View

Comment: You beat me in answering speed :)

Note, you do not need to use `@model dynamic`, completely omitting `@model` has the same effect

Comment: If i use dynamic how would i access the items in the var from the view?

Comment: In the same way you would if it was a strongly types model, e.g Model.CastGoodSum

Comment: Having a bit of a problem. When running the code my VAR GoodProduct = {CastGood = 690, GoodScrap = 0} in my view i have '@Model.CastGood i get error along the lines @Model Does not contain definition for CastGood. How do i access these items in GoodProduct